# Python. Как ввести числа из одной строки в цикле?

Tags: python, строки, циклы, ввод

В цикле мне нужно по одному вводить значения из строки (не из строки, как из типа, а, т. е. вводимые числа вводятся на одной строке), каждый проход цикла мне надо взять присваивать переменной новое следующее значение
Как это сделать?

Пример:
пользователь вводит в одной строке числа:
1 3 7 10
В первый проход цикла я присваиваю переменной значение 1, во второй 3, в третий 7 и т.д.

Да не будет ошибок компиляции у того, кто ответит! :)

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Приведите пример хоть какой-то

Comment: Пример:
пользователь вводит в одной строке числа:
1 3 7 10
В первый проход цикла я присваиваю переменной значение 1, во второй 3, в третий 7 и т.д.

Comment: Добавте ваш код, пусть даже с ошибками.

Answer (score 2):

Вот:

```
In [29]: def foo():
    ...:     value = input('Enter a value: ')
    ...:     for i in map(int, value.split()):
    ...:         your_var = i
    ...:         print('your_var = ', your_var) # Для примера выводим ваши числа
    ...:

In [30]: foo()
Enter a value: 1 2 3 4 10 20 25
your_var =  1
your_var =  2
your_var =  3
your_var =  4
your_var =  10
your_var =  20
your_var =  25
```

Comment: Для коротких строк введённых интерактивно `for number in map(int, input('Enter numbers: ').split()): ..`. Для больших строк из файла: [How to read tokens without reading whole line or file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20019503/4279)

Comment: @jfs спасибо за замечание

Comment: пример кода у вас и до этого нормальный был (и без `map()` даже более понятный для новичков -- я просто для краткости в комментарии так написал). Суть комментария, что есть способы (mmap+re), которые не требуют всю строчку в память читать (чисто формально это позволяет "по одному вводить значения из строки", но так я сильно сомневаюсь, что от автора именно этого буквально требовали, то ограничился комментарием).